# no puedo desabilitar servicios ni cerrar puertos en ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, nmap

he escaneado mi red con nmap.

```
Host is up (0.000047s latency).
Not shown: 1995 closed ports
PORT     STATE         SERVICE
25/tcp   open          smtp
68/udp   open|filtered dhcpc
631/udp  open|filtered ipp
5353/udp open|filtered zeroconf
5355/udp open|filtered llmnr
```

con sudo /etc/init.d/zeroconf disable no consigo nada.

con el gufw he creado las reglas para cerrar los puertos 5353 y 5355 pero siguen abiertos.

¿que puedo hacer?

Comment: Ha probado con iptables?

Comment: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5353 -j DROP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomendaria usar el siguiente firewall.

**UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall)**

Es el que uso y me ha funcionado correctamente, y facil de usar.

Instalación:

```
root@linux:~# apt-get install ufw
```

Activar el registro de eventos

```
root@linux:~# ufw logging on
```

Activar acceso mediante SSH

```
root@linux:~# ufw allow ssh/tcp
```

Activar el Firewall

```
root@linux:~# ufw enable
```

Verificar el estatus del Firewall

```
root@linux:~# ufw status verbose
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bloquear los puertos 5353 y 5355

```
root@linux:~# ufw deny 5353
root@linux:~# ufw deny 5355
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un link para que puedas verificar un poco más sobre su uso.
[Tutorial de UFW](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server)